# Send a transaction using web3js1.0: Error: Invalid JSON RPC response: ""

Tags: web3js

When I send a transaction to ethereum testnet rinkeby by infura node using web3js interface, I met the error "Error: Invalid JSON RPC response：""". This is my source code :

```
let Web3 = require("web3");
if(typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
    web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
} else {
    web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/2f85c22a29994320b52da33bec96968d"));
}
let abi = "/abi/"
let address = "";
let contract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, address);
contract.methods.set("JJJJJJJJJ").send({from: '0x1062024529684b1890b2fa5964334d8db7da2512'},function(err, txHash) {
        if(err) {
            console.log("err: " + err);
        } else {
            console.log(txHash);
        }
});
```

Comment: Where are you getting v3 from? It should be v1.

Answer (score 0):

Usually web3 initialization will take few mins, so please use await, async method for web3 initialization.

For example:

```
async function abc() {
    web3 = await new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/2f85c22a29994320b52da33bec96968d"));
}
```